# Equal dot spacing in table of contents and glossary

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries, tocloft

I want to make the dot separations I get using `\dotfill` in the `glossaries` package to match the dot separation I get in the `tocloft` package. The image below shows an entry from the table of contents on the top and an entry from the glossary on the bottom:

[image: compare]

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85338/7275), I can create a command called `\Dotfill` which has different spacing than `\dotfill`. Below is the definition for `\Dotfill` where the space between dots in `.33em`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand \Dotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .33em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother
```

I can then use `\Dotfill` to [add dots after the description](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83327/7275) in my glossary:

```
renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\Dotfill}
```

I can manually change `.33em` until the dot spacing appears to match, but is there a better way to do this? According to the [documentation for tocloft](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf), the value describing the space between the dots in the table of contents is given by `\@dotsep` which has default value 4.5. I am not sure how to utilize this in what is given above.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand \Dotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .33em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\Dotfill}

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{Cab}{name={$C[a,b]$},sort=C,description={The space of continuous functions defined on $[a,b]$}}

\tableofcontents

\printglossary

\chapter{Chap 1}

\gls{Cab}

\end{document}
```

To compile, you must run `makeglossaries` in between calls to `latex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to know the lengths or give them explicitly (which is surely prone to error). Simply use the settings from `tocloft` in your definition of `\Dotfill`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand\Dotfill{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\Dotfill}

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{Cab}{name={$C[a,b]$},sort=C,description={The space of continuous functions defined on $[a,b]$}}

\tableofcontents

\printglossary

\chapter{Chap 1}

\gls{Cab}

\end{document}
```

You can even do without the `\Dotfill` command:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{Cab}{name={$C[a,b]$},sort=C,description={The space of continuous functions defined on $[a,b]$}}

\tableofcontents

\printglossary

\chapter{Chap 1}

\gls{Cab}

\end{document}
```

The ToC

[image]

The entry in the glossary:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the value 4.5 to em to get the correct number.
As is in the documentation, the 4.5 is in `math units`. There are `18` math units to `1` em.

18 / 4.5 = 4, so 4.5 math units is 1/4 * 1 em = 0.25 em.

Using the value `0.25 em` will give you the correct standard spacing used by tocloft.

Comment: When I use `.25em` in the MWE above, it makes the dots even closer together than if I just used `\dotfill`.

Comment: That might be, but then for whatever reason the default values of tocloft are not being used. According to the documentation, the default is 4.5 mu = 0.25 em. If the spacing than is not correct, the default values are altered somehow. However, Gonzalo's answer is definitely a better solution, even though it doesn't answer to question on how to use the 4.5 value :-)