# Dot spaces in Contents and Index

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, indexing

First an MWE and its output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\AddIndexLetterToTOC}[1]{\textbf{#1}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.mst}
headings_flag 1 %
heading_prefix "\\AddIndexLetterToTOC{"
    heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test chapter}

\index{And}
\index{Book}
\index{Summer}
\index{Latex}

\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

As you see, the dot spaces in Contents and Index are different, so

**(question 1) is there any way to make the dot space in Index be the same as that in Contents, and to keep the dot space in Contents be unchanged?**

I know [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118025/140814) with the help of the `tocloft` package which I don't want to use since it will change some other setting in my `.tex` files. Or

**(question 2) is there any way to make the dot space in Contents be the same as that in Index, and to keep the dot space in Index be unchanged?**

By the way, the definition of `\@dottedtocline` for Contents is as follows:

```
\ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
\vskip \z@ \@plus .2\p@ 
{\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip 
\@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip \parindent #2\relax 
\@afterindenttrue \interlinepenalty \@M \leavevmode 
\@tempdima #3\relax 
\advance \leftskip \@tempdima \null \nobreak 
\hskip -\leftskip {#4}\nobreak
\leaders \hbox {$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}
\hfill \nobreak 
\hb@xt@ \@pnumwidth {\hfil \normalfont \normalcolor #5}\par }
\fi
```

and the definition for `\dotfill` for Index is also as follows:

```
\def\dotfill{\leaders\hbox to.6em{\hss .\hss}\hskip\z@ plus 1fill\kern\z@}%
```

But I don't know how to get the desired result after reading them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TeX primitive which generates repeated dots is

```
\leaders <box or rule> <glue>
```

If the `<box>` is used (this is your case, the box includes the dot) then this box is repeated in the area where `<glue>` is stretched.

In your first snippet, `\leaders` is used as

```
\leaders \hbox {$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$} \hfill
```

The box is constructed here more complicated way than needed (unfortunately, this is very common in LaTeX's internal sources). The dot is put in `\hbox` in math mode and kerns around it is expressed in `mu` units (math units, 1/18 em). The `\@dotsep` is defined in `book.cls` as 4.5, so we have 4.5/18 = 0.25 em here. The same can be expressed without math mode as

```
\leaders \hbox{\kern.25em .\kern.25em} \hfill
```

The width of the dot vary depending on the font used. For example, if Computer Modern at 10pt is used, then the dot has its width 2.7777pt and 1em = 10pt. The width of our box is 7.7777pt and we can express the same by

```
\leaders \hbox to .7777em {\hss .\hss} \hfill
```

You can see that dots used in the Index is created by

```
\leaders \hbox to .6em {\hss .\hss} \hskip 0pt plus 1fill
```

Note that `\hfill` is primitive equivalent to `\hskip 0pt plus 1fill`. So there is no difference. The difference is in the width of the repated boxes.

We cannot compare the width of `\hbox` used in the TOC with the width used in the Index without knowing about the width of the dot, which is font dependent value. I suggest to use the same width in both cases, for example replace
the `\leaders` in the TOC macro by

```
\leaders \hbox to .6em {\hss .\hss} \hfill
```

and you have the same dots (with narrower spaces) in both: TOC and Index.

Or replace the `\leaders` in both, in the Index macro and in the TOC macro by

```
\leaders \hbox to .77777em {\hss .\hss} \hfill
```

and you have the same dots (with wider spaces) in TOC and Index.
As mentioned above, the original usage of `\leaders` in the TOC macro is, unfortunately, over-killed.

---

(**The following is edited by the OP**) So to get as what is asked in the first question, modify the definition of `\dotfill` as follows which is equivalent to @Jinwen 's **old answer**:

```
\makeatletter
\def\dotfill{\leaders\hbox to .7777em {\hss .\hss}\hfill\nobreak}%
\makeatother
```

and to get as what is asked in the second question, modify the definition of `\@dottedtocline` as follows in your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders \hbox to .6em {\hss .\hss}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5%
                        \kern-\p@\kern\p@}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Could you show how to replace the `\leaders` in the TOC macro in details?

Comment: Copy `\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{...}` from the `latex.ltx` file, modify it and save it to your macros. Of course, your macros are surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in your macro file.

Comment: I wrote it clearly in the comment.

Comment: The name of `latex.ltx` changed? And where to find the file?

Comment: In TeXlive, I see the `latex.ltx`  in `texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/`. I supposed that you know about this file because you cited from it in your OP: "By the way, the definition of `\@dottedtocline` for Contents is as follows".

Comment: Well, the path changed a little in the new version: `\texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/` in the MacTeX.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have the same dots style everywhere in your document, you can simply define your own version. For example, in my document class, I have (of course the color is a little different):

```
\titlerule*[.67em]{\textcolor{gray!55}{.}}
```

*(I think this is a command from the packages `titlesec` or `titletoc`, hopefully these packages won't break your existed settings. Anyway, this serves just as an indication, you may define your own version without using any further packages)*

or the plain form

```
\leaders \hbox to .67em {\hss \textcolor{gray!55}{.} \hss} \hfill
```

(This works surprisingly well as it produces a perfect horizontal alignment)

In the `.mst` file there is:

```
delim_0 "\\IndexDotfill " % Filler between section heading and page number
delim_1 "\\IndexDotfill " % Filler between subsection heading and page number
```

where `\IndexDotfill` is defined as

```
\newcommand*{\IndexDotfill}
  {
    \leaders \hbox to .67em {\hss \textcolor{main-text!15!paper}{.} \hss} \hfill
  }
```

And in the configuration of ToC, I have something like:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}
      [2em] % 0em (part) + 2em
      {\addvspace{.5pc}\normalfont}
      {\contentslabel{2em}}
      {\hspace*{-2em}}
      {\titlerule*[1em]{\textcolor{gray!55}{.}}\contentspage}
```

The result looks like:

[image]

[image]

---

**Old answer**

As already indicated by yourself in your question, if you redefine `\dotfill` to be

```
\def\dotfill{\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern\@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill\nobreak}
```

Then you will have the same dots as in the ToC :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\AddIndexLetterToTOC}[1]{\textbf{#1}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\def\dotfill{\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern\@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill\nobreak}%
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.mst}
headings_flag 1 %
heading_prefix "\\AddIndexLetterToTOC{"
    heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test chapter}

\index{And}
\index{Book}
\index{Summer}
\index{Latex}

\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's quite strange that I've ever tried this way while it's not successful. Maybe I miss `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`?

Comment: Thanks very much! Since I could accept only one answer and @wipet 's answer shows two ways, I have to accept his answer, while vote your answer once.

Comment: @M.Logic I just updated my answer, hopefully this would be helpful to you (and thanks to this opportunity, I found that the dots in my index are not properly aligned, working on it...)

Comment: @M.Logic I owe you a huge thank you for your question. Now that I know about `\leaders` I rewrote the command for the dots fill in index and the dots are finally vertically aligned :)