# How to print glossaries before `\gls`

Tags: glossaries

I'm using `glossaries` package to build a `List of Symbols` for my thesis template to obtain something like this:
[image]

and here is my `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newglossary{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}

\newglossaryentry{des}{type=symbols,name={DES},sort=des,
    description={Discrete-Event Systems}}
\newglossaryentry{sct}{type=symbols,name={SCT},sort=sct,
    description={Supervisory Control Theory}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

    \blindtext[3]

    \gls{des}

    \blindtext[3]
    \blindtext[3]

    \gls{sct}

    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Leading to:

[image]

however, it is not exactly what it should be.

First of all, I need to add those dots between the description and the page number. Second, the glossary should have been printed before the text; since I need to place the `List of Symbols` right before the main text (just like `List of Figures`, etc.). But the problem is that I have to call `\printglossaries` right after all `gls` entries, then the list will be located at the end of the text.

How can I resolve these cases?

Comment: Put \printglossaries to the beginning.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman: Thanks. Have you any idea for automatic generation of those dots?

Comment: This is another question. I guess it has to be on this site.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman: It is actually the first part of this question. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83327/89417