# Flush page number at right in glossary

Tags: horizontal-alignment, page-numbering, glossaries

How can we flush right the page number in the glossary/index considering the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=super]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{label}{name={Name}, description={Description}}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

... which gives this output

[image]

I want the page number to be at the far right of the page, is it possible to do so ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Troy, the solution is to load a different style :

```
\usepackage[style=super4col]{glossaries}
```

do the job.

A comprehensive list of glossaries styles can be found [here](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/).

Answer (score 2):

It could be also done with `style=super`. Here is a step-by-step solution. At the end i added another alternative with `\usepackage{glossary-superragged}`. But first i will start with adaptions to your mwe.

1. (OPTIONAL) Visualize the margins with `\usepackage{showframe}`
2. (OPTIONAL) Visualize borders of the style `super` with `superborder` `\usepackage[style=superborder,automake]{glossaries}`. Later you could use the original `\usepackage[style=super,automake]{glossaries}` without lines around it.
3. Shift page number to the right with `\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\hfill}`. Similar to [@clemens answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83327/124842).
4. For the next step you need `\usepackage{calc}`. Have a look to [15.1.5 Supertabular Styles](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries),p.226 and redefine `glsdescwidth`  so that it fits the rest of the page. Done with `\setlength\glsdescwidth{\textwidth-\widthof{longest Name}-4\tabcolsep}`. Note: Instead of `longest Name` you have to write always your longest glossaries entry.

**Results** with `superborder`, `border` and as an alternative`glossary-supperragged`:

[image]

**MWE:** `style=super`/ `superborder`(=super with horizontal and vertical
lines around it)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[style=super,automake]{glossaries}
%OR \usepackage[style=superborder,automake]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\hfill}

\usepackage{calc}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{label}{name={Name}, description={Description}}
\newglossaryentry{labelLong}{name={longest Name}, description={Description}}
\begin{document}
\setlength\glsdescwidth{\textwidth-\widthof{longest Name}-4\tabcolsep}

\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

**MWE:** alternative with `glossary-supperragged`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-superragged}
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\hfill}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{label}{name={Name}, description={Description}}
\newglossaryentry{labelLong}{name={longest Name}, description={Description}}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```